How can I estimate the following integral: $\int _{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ x }}} (1-e^{-t}) ^{a-1} e^{-xt} \ dt = x^{-a} \Gamma(a) +O(x^{-a-1})$
In my book, it showed this result: when $x\to \infty$ , we have:  $$\begin{align*}
I = \int _{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ x }}} (1-e^{-t}) ^{a-1} e^{-xt} \ dt = x^{-a} \Gamma(a) +O(x^{-a-1})
\end{align*}$$ where $a>1$ , $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function.
The reasoning is the following: as $x\to \infty$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ x }}\to 0$ , we have $t\to 0$ . Thus, by Taylor expansion, we have $1-e^{-t}= t+O(t^{2})$. Thus $$\begin{align*}
I &=  \int _{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ x }}} \left( t+O(t^{2}) \right)^{a-1} e^{-xt} \ dt
\\ &= \int _{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ x }}} t^{a-1} (1+O(t))^{a-1} e^{-xt} \ dt
\end{align*}$$ Then, since $O(t)\to 0$ , by using $(1+x)^{a}=1+ax+O(x^{2}),x\to 0$ , we have $(1+O(t))^{a-1}=1+(a-1)O(t)=1+O(t)$ when $t\to 0$ . Thus, we further have $$\begin{align*}
I&=  \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ x }}} t^{a-1} (1+O(t)) e^{-xt} \ dt
\\ &= \underbrace{ \int _{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ x }}} t^{a-1} e^{-xt} \ dt }_{ I_{1} } +\underbrace{ \int _{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{ x }}} O(t^{a}e^{-xt}) \ dt }_{ I_{2} }
\end{align*}$$
For $I_{2}$ , I know that it is $O(x^{-a-1})$ by using substitution $xt=s$
For $I_{1}$ , use the same substitution $xt=s$ , we have $$\begin{align*}
I_{1} &= \int _{0}^{\sqrt[]{ x }} \left( \frac{s}{x} \right)^{a-1} e^{-s} \frac{1}{x} ds 
\\ &=  x^{-a} \int _{0}^{\sqrt[]{ x }} s^{a-1} e^{-s} \ ds
\end{align*}$$ Then I can see that $x\to \infty$ , we have $\int_{0}^{\sqrt[]{ x }}s^{a-1} e^{-s} \ ds \to\Gamma(a)$ , so I can write $$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\sqrt[]{ x }}s^{a-1} e^{-s} \ ds=\Gamma(a) +o(1)
\end{align*}$$ Then I have $$\begin{align*}
I_{1} =x^{-a}(\Gamma(a)+o(1))=  x^{-a}\Gamma(a) +o(x^{-a})
\end{align*}$$ Then finally I have $$\begin{align*}
I = I_{1}+I_{2} = x^{-a} \Gamma(a) + o(x^{-a}) +O(x^{-a-1})
\end{align*}$$ I got stucked for dealing with $o(x^{-a})$ . Since $o(x^{-a})$  means that it is a function $\varphi(x)$ such that $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists R: \forall x> R\implies |\varphi(x)|<\epsilon x^{-a}$ . Then it doesn't imply that $\varphi(x)=O(x^{-a-1})$ since if $\varphi(x)= x^{-\rho}: 1< a<\rho<1+a$ . Then we indeed have $x^{a-\rho}$ goes to $0$ when $x\to \infty$ since $a-\rho<0$  . However, we can't have $\varphi(x) =O(x^{-a-1})$ since $x^{a+1-\rho}$ have positive exponent, so it goes to $\infty$ and can not be bounded by some positive number.
Thus, I guess something goes wrong when I use $\int_{0}^{\sqrt[]{ x }}s^{a-1} e^{-s} \ ds=\Gamma(a) +o(1),x\to \infty$ . The $o(1)$ may be replaced by a more precise estimate. Any help on this? Thanks!

Edit:
If it's possible, do not use the Stirling Formula, since this is one of the steps of proving it.

Note that
$$
\int_0^{\sqrt x } {s^{a - 1} {\rm e}^{ - s} {\rm d}s}  = \Gamma (a) - \int_{\sqrt x }^{ + \infty } {s^{a - 1} {\rm e}^{ - s} {\rm d}s} .
$$
Performing the change of variables $s = (1 + t)\sqrt x$ and $u=1+t$ gives
\begin{align*}
0\le \int_{\sqrt x }^{ + \infty } {s^{a - 1} {\rm e}^{ - s} {\rm d}s} & = x^{a/2} {\rm e}^{ - \sqrt x } \int_0^{ + \infty } {(1+t)^{a - 1} {\rm e}^{ - t\sqrt x } {\rm d}t} \\ & \le x^{a/2} {\rm e}^{ - \sqrt x } \int_0^{ + \infty } {(1+t)^{a - 1} {\rm e}^{ - t} {\rm d}t} \\ & = x^{a/2} {\rm e}^{ 1- \sqrt x } \int_1^{ + \infty } {u^{a - 1} {\rm e}^{ -u} {\rm d}u} \\ & \le \mathrm{e}\,\Gamma (a)x^{a/2} {\rm e}^{ - \sqrt x }
\end{align*}
for $x\ge 1$. Clearly,
$$
\mathrm{e}\,\Gamma (a)x^{a/2} {\rm e}^{ - \sqrt x }  = \mathcal{O}(x^{ - 1} )
$$
as $x\to+\infty$, with any fixed $a>1$. (In fact, $x^{a/2} {\rm e}^{ - \sqrt x }  \le (a + 2)^{a + 2} {\rm e}^{ - (a + 2)} x^{ - 1} $, for $x\ge 1$ and $a>1$.)

Nice substitution brother! I think there may be a little computation mistake there. Using your substitution, we have  $I=  \int _{0}^{\infty}\left[  (1+t)\sqrt[]{ x } \right]^{a-1} e^{-(1+t)\sqrt[]{ x }} \sqrt[]{ x } \ dt= x^{a/2} e^{-\sqrt[]{ x }} \int _{0}^{\infty} (1+t)^{a-1} e^{-t\sqrt[]{ x }} \ dt$. Then we use $u=1+t$ so we have $I\leq x^{a/2} e^{-\sqrt[]{ x }+1} \Gamma(a)$. But the result is generally unchanged. Thank you.

EDIT: Ah oh well. Given the OP's edit of avoiding the Stirling formula, the below might not be all that helpful...
Let us take a bit of a different approach by first substituting $u=1-e^{-t}$. This yields
$$I=\int_0^{1-e^{-1/\sqrt{x}}} u^{a-1} (1-u)^{x-1}\,\text{d}u = B(x,a) + R(x,a).$$
Here, $B(a,x) = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(a+x)}$ is the Beta function and the remainder is given by
\begin{align}
R(x,a) &= \int_{1-e^{-1/\sqrt{x}}}^1 u^{a-1} (1-u)^{x-1}\,\text{d}u.
\end{align}
For sufficiently large $x$, $1-e^{-1/\sqrt{x}} > \frac{b}{\sqrt{x}}$ ($b<1$), so
\begin{align}
R(x,a) &< \int_{\frac{b}{\sqrt{x}}}^1 u^{a-1} (1-u)^{x-1}\,\text{d}u < \int_{\frac{b}{\sqrt{x}}}^1 (1-u)^{x-1}\,\text{d}u \\
&= \frac{1}{x}(1-u)^x \bigg\vert_1^{\frac{b}{\sqrt{x}}} = \frac{1}{x}\left(1-\frac{b}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^x \sim \frac{1}{x} e^{-b\sqrt{x}}.
\end{align}
So, $R$ is exponentially small. But what about the Beta function?
Using
\begin{align}
\frac{(a+x)!}{x!} &\sim (a+x)^{a+x} / x^{-x} e^{-a} = x^a e^{-a} (1 + a/x)^{x} = x^a e^{-a} e^{x\log(1+a/x)}\\
&= x^a e^{-a^2/(2x) + \mathcal{O}(x^{-2})} \sim x^a \left( 1 - \frac{a^2}{2x} + \mathcal{O}(x^{-2}) \right)
\end{align}
gives
$$I\sim B(x,a) \sim \Gamma(a) x^{-a} \left( 1 - \frac{a^2}{2x} + \mathcal{O}(x^{-2}) \right) = \Gamma(a)x^{-a} + \mathcal{O}(x^{-a-1}).$$
On a side note, the precise correction term I derived above seems to make the approximation slightly worse than only keeping the leading order (asymptotically it of course holds though). Maybe I made a numerical mistake somewhere, but the $\mathcal{O}$-part should hold regardless.
